# Реализация чистой логики после onFailure в MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, архитектура, kotlin

Обучаю себя чистому коду и **MVVM**. Возник вопрос...

И так, есть **BaseViewModel**, в котором ничего толком не выполняется, только хранятся данные в виде **MutableLiveData**. Тут же я храню результаты запросов. Сами запросы аккуратно лежат в **ScheduleRepository**. Его объект создается при создании `BaseViewModel`.

В **MainActivity** инициализирую несколько `obserListener`-ов, например:

```
viewModel?.isLoading?.observe(this, Observer<Boolean> { isLoading ->
    waitProgressbar.visibility = if (isLoading!!)
        View.VISIBLE
    else
        View.GONE
})

viewModel?.message?.observe(this, Observer<String> { message ->
    Snackbar.make(fragmentFrame, message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setDuration(2000).show()
})
```

Соответственно в `BaseViewModel` существуют эти поля:

```
var isLoading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
var message: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

Поля меняются здесь же. Отправили запрос, установили `isLoading = true`. Запрос выполнился, установили false, изменение переменной перехватилось обсервером, анимация скрылась. Вроде бы все хорошо, но...

В случае, если запрос выполнился с ошибкой, необходимо показать сообщение со стандартной ошибкой. Все запросы в  **ScheduleRepository**. Согласно гугл апи это единственный экземляр при инициализации ViewModel-и. Однако как я могу установить поле `message` из этого презентера, если ссылки на `ViewModel` внутри нет? В итоге, я добавляю отдельный метод, прокидывающий внутрь `ScheduleRepository` модель и контекст. Я не считаю, что это верно, но я не могу придумать, как это сделать чисто.

Приведу кода `ScheduleRepository`:

```
class ScheduleRepository {
    private var viewModel: BaseViewModel? = null
    private var context: Context? = null

    fun setViewModel(context: Context, viewModel: BaseViewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel
        this.context = context
    }

    fun getWeek(groupId: String, date: String): MutableLiveData<RequestResultWeek> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<RequestResultWeek>()

        getAPIService().getWeek(groupId, date).enqueue(object: Callback<RequestResultWeek> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RequestResultWeek>?, t: Throwable?) {
                viewModel?.isLoading?.value = false
                viewModel?.title?.value = context?.getString(R.string.request_error)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<RequestResultWeek>?, response: Response<RequestResultWeek>?) {
                data.postValue(response?.body())
            }
        })

        return data
    }
}
```

как обыграть это чисто? Жду ваши идеи и опыт!

Comment: Посмотрите в доках на класс NetworkBoundResource. Как раз для этих целей. Минимум кода, максимум пользы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось решить проблему. Не идеально, конечно, потому как я нарушаю некоторые принципы абстракции, но думаю решение получиось более менее красивое. И так. Поля, относящиеся к косметической отрисовке, вынесены в отдельную модель: **CosmeticView** и оформлены в виде `MutableData`:

```
class CosmeticView {
    var showBackBtn: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    var isLoading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    var message: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    var title: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

Объект `CosmeticView` иницилизуерся внутри **BaseViewModel**:

```
var cosmeticView: CosmeticView = CosmeticView()
```

Он передается в качестве параметров запросов. Например, запрос с неделями.

Код из `BaseViewModel`:

```
fun getWeek(groupId: String, period: LocalDate): MutableLiveData<RequestResultWeek>? {

    if (this.groupId != groupId || this.period != period) {
        this.groupId = groupId
        this.period = period

        week = repository.getWeek(groupId, getStringFromDate(period), cosmeticView)
    }

    return week
}
```

Часть кода из Репозитория:

```
fun getWeek(groupId: String, date: String, cosmeticView: CosmeticView): MutableLiveData<RequestResultWeek> {
    val data = MutableLiveData<RequestResultWeek>()
    cosmeticView.isLoading.value = true

    getAPIService().getWeek(groupId, date).enqueue(object: Callback<RequestResultWeek> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<RequestResultWeek>?, t: Throwable?) {
            cosmeticView.isLoading.value = false
            cosmeticView.message.value = t?.message
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<RequestResultWeek>?, response: Response<RequestResultWeek>?) {
            cosmeticView.isLoading.value = false
            data.postValue(response?.body())
        }
    })

    return data
}
```

Перед запросом включается анимация загрузки. По завершению загрузки, анимация выключается, а в случае возникновения ошибки устанавливается текст, который будет выведен. В `MainActivity` обработка все так же через `observe`.

```
private fun initObservers() {
    viewModel?.cosmeticView?.isLoading?.observe(this, Observer<Boolean> { isLoading ->
        waitProgressbar.visibility = if (isLoading!!)
            View.VISIBLE
        else
            View.GONE
    })

    viewModel?.cosmeticView?.showBackBtn?.observe(this, Observer<Boolean> { showBackBtn ->
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(showBackBtn!!)
    })

    viewModel?.cosmeticView?.title?.observe(this, Observer<String> { title ->
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        if (title != null) {
            supportActionBar?.show()
            supportActionBar?.title = title
        } else
            supportActionBar?.hide()
    })

    viewModel?.cosmeticView?.message?.observe(this, Observer<String> { message ->
        Snackbar.make(fragmentFrame, message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setDuration(2000).show()
    })
}
```

Я попробовал сделать 1 обработчик для `CosmeticView`, но тогда нужно разбираться с ложными срабатываниями, например: изменилась анимация, а я вместе с анимацией случайно показываю сообщение. Для простоты не стал стягивать все в одно место, обработчик.

**Итог**

Скорее всего есть решения более высокого качества, но пока оставляю этот вариант. Передача объекта `CosmeticView` в репозиторий, выглядит аккуратнее нежеле передача все модели и контекста в придачу. К абсолютной абстракции я не стремлюсь, т.к. считаю, что она нужна только для крупных и очень крупных проектах, с большими командами. Мой проект крошечный (что говорить, всего 3 вида запросов). Если же у кто-то есть идеи с другими вариантами, или вы можете улучшить этот - обязательно пишите. В споре рождается истина.